# Error 1004 on Resizing range and Transposing array

Tags: excel, vba

I will not post full code since it's quite huge - I will focus on a part that is causing an error.

The macro is supposed to copy URL's generated in excel, open them in IE, copy source code to another sheet, look for something in this code, save results in specific cell, remove sheet and go to next URL. It works quite well, it copies the source codes for many URLs, but for some URLs it just fails. When I open the URLs manually - they work perfectly, but somehow Excel throws me an error for them.

Could you guys check the below could to help me better understand where is the problem?

Here are two samples links:

This one works good - [link1](https://ext-isztar4.mf.gov.pl/taryfa_celna/measure.xhtml?cnCode=4811419000&lang=EN&date=201906027&cssfile=tarbro)
This one throws error 1004 - [link2](https://ext-isztar4.mf.gov.pl/taryfa_celna/measure.xhtml?cnCode=8523520000&lang=EN&date=201906027&cssfile=tarbro)

And here is the code:

```vb
    Sub CC_Check()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument

Dim URL As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("One Code")

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

Set Rng = ws1.Range("A3:A18")

For Each URL In Rng

ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = ws1.Cells(URL.Row, 2).Value & "_" & ws1.Cells(6, 7).Value

ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate URL.Value

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Set html = ie.document

Range("A1").Value = html.DocumentElement.outerHTML

Dim arr

arr = Split(html.DocumentElement.outerHTML, vbLf)

Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr) '<-- this line causing error 1004
```

Comment: How many dimensions is your array `arr`?

Comment: application.transpose is limited to array with dimension less than 32767.

Comment: if your your array size > 65 K, Try to loop through the array

Comment: Thanks guys, never thought about that and it made me change the code a little bit to use InStr to search for the text instead of pasting the source code and transposing it - now it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Application.Transpose` has a number of problems. It fails when

- The array has only one member (`UBound(arr) = 1`)
- One of the strings has a length > 32K (but I have seen other cases where it failed already when a string had more that 255 chars)
- The array size is larger than 64K (however, in Excel 2016 this will not cause a runtime error but a crippled array with less size

So, bet bet is to do the transform by hand which is rather easy. You should, by the way, use a `Worksheet`-variable for the sheets you add - never rely on `Activesheet`. The following code will create the new sheet only if it doesn't exist (else it will clear it's content so you can run the code several times

```
Set newWs = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set newWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName)
On Error GoTo 0
If newWs Is Nothing Then
    ' Sheet doesn't exist, create a new one and name it
    Set newWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    newWs.Name = ws1.Cells(URL.row, 2).Value & "x" & ws1.Cells(6, 7).Value
Else
    ' Sheet already there, clear its content
     newWs.UsedRange.ClearContents
End If

    (..Load HTML and split..)

' Do your own transpose into a 2nd array and dump that into sheet
Dim brr
ReDim brr(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)  ' Make it 2-dimensional
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    brr(i, 1) = arr(i)
Next i
Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1).Value = brr
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I decided to try another approach, instead of transpoisng the source code to find the string using InStr so no more array issues.